# Manifest and uses permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, android-permissions

I've got an Android project to build ( never been deploying anything on Android before ). The project build does not work. `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `instant-run` getting inside `<application>` tag `<uses-permission>` tags. Which is not going to work - it is not allowed by google docs.

My main manifest looks like:

```
<manifest package="xxx"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        android:name="XXX"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxx"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**The build version:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.touspolska.mobile"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.0.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Permissions required for GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:name="XXX.TousPolskaApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="XXX.WebViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

...
// HERE IS ERROR!!!!
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <permission
            android:name="XXX.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="XXX.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
// ERROR ABOVE !!!!
....
</application>
```

**ERROR**
Android resource linking failed - it is pointing to those 3 lines which are between error comments

As we can see it has werid `uses-permissions`. Does anyone know what is including these deprecated tags inside manifest ?

Comment: Do you have another modules in your project?

Comment: There is only one.

Comment: Any library you declare in dependencies section of your application build.gradle file may add something to your manifest. It's called manifest merging https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, open your AndroidManifest.xml and click on Merged Manifest tab in the bottom. You will get more info on modules/libraries contributions to it

Comment: C2DM permissions were used by GCM (deprecated in favor of FCM)

Comment: @Amaksoft you are right, some dependencies are adding these things. How can I disabled them ?

Comment: You can disable dependencies by commenting them out in build.gradle. But it will fail your build  if they are used in your code. The other way is to control manifest merging as described here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#node_markers

Comment: I don't know what dependencies are you using, but if they use incorrect manifest entries, they are probably obsolete and should be updated or replaced

Comment: Also your build tools may be too new or too old (depending on how old is your project and whether it was successfully built before)